# Visual Studio 2012 - C# - outlook 2013 Add on

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

Is it possible to make a butoon at Ribbon be visible only when a email window is open? I don't want to be visible at the default outlook ribbon when the application loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: No, any idea from where to start? I am trying to find any sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. If you use the Ribbon Designer you can set the RibbonType property of the OfficeRibbon class. Set the property to the Compose or Read property values.

[image]

If you use the XML markup, you need to check out the RibbonID parameter passed to the GetCustomUI method of the IRibbonExtensibility interface. See [Implementing the IRibbonExtensibility Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868522.aspx) for more information.